# Textmate not picking up PATH

Tags: bash, textmate

Textmate does not source my .profile file. I don't have a custom bash_init.rb, nor do I have a .bash_profile or .bash_login in my home directory (the other two files it checks first).

My .profile gets sourced properly when I start up terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This describes how Textmate sources the PATH, it talks about Ruby specifically but is applicable to anything.

http://wiki.macromates.com/Troubleshooting/RubyVersionIssue

Comment: I had seen that, but everything in there tells me my current setup should work. I have a .profile, but none of the other files (.bash_{profile,login} or bash_init.sh), so it should source my .profile, which handles the PATH setup

Comment: Read the page again, there are two different places sourced. One is used for #! commands the other for bash commands. You need to setup both.